The point cloud display is incomplete when I use Qt, VTK, and PCL to display PCD point clouds
The program running environment is:
Qt 5.15.2, PCL 1.14.1, VTK 9.3, Visual Studio 2022, Windows 10.
The point cloud is a randomly generated point cloud.
Actually, I also used other point cloud models, and the result was the same.
The source code is as follows:
main.cpp
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>

#include <QtCore/QVariant>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtWidgets/QMenuBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QStatusBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QToolBar>
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>
#include <qvtkopenglnativewidget.h>

#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/io/ply_io.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h>
#include <vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow.h>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

class Ui_QtPCLDemoClass
{
public:
    QWidget* centralWidget;
    QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget* openGLWidget;
    QMenuBar* menuBar;
    QToolBar* mainToolBar;
    QStatusBar* statusBar;

    void setupUi(QMainWindow* QtPCLDemoClass)
    {
        if (QtPCLDemoClass->objectName().isEmpty())
            QtPCLDemoClass->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("QtPCLDemoClass"));
        QtPCLDemoClass->resize(1202, 844);
        centralWidget = new QWidget(QtPCLDemoClass);
        centralWidget->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("centralWidget"));
        openGLWidget = new QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget(centralWidget);
        openGLWidget->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("openGLWidget"));
        openGLWidget->setGeometry(QRect(10, 10, 1081, 691));
        QtPCLDemoClass->setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
        menuBar = new QMenuBar(QtPCLDemoClass);
        menuBar->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("menuBar"));
        menuBar->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 1202, 23));
        QtPCLDemoClass->setMenuBar(menuBar);
        mainToolBar = new QToolBar(QtPCLDemoClass);
        mainToolBar->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("mainToolBar"));
        QtPCLDemoClass->addToolBar(Qt::TopToolBarArea, mainToolBar);
        statusBar = new QStatusBar(QtPCLDemoClass);
        statusBar->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("statusBar"));
        QtPCLDemoClass->setStatusBar(statusBar);

        retranslateUi(QtPCLDemoClass);

        QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(QtPCLDemoClass);
    } // setupUi

    void retranslateUi(QMainWindow* QtPCLDemoClass)
    {
        QtPCLDemoClass->setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication::translate("QtPCLDemoClass", "QtPCLDemo", nullptr));
    } // retranslateUi

};

namespace Ui {
    class QtPCLDemoClass : public Ui_QtPCLDemoClass {};
} // namespace Ui

QT_END_NAMESPACE

class QtPCLDemo : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QtPCLDemo(QWidget* parent = nullptr);

private:
    Ui::QtPCLDemoClass ui;

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud;
    boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> view;
};

QtPCLDemo::QtPCLDemo(QWidget* parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow> renderWindow =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkGenericOpenGLRenderWindow>::New();
    renderWindow->AddRenderer(renderer);
    view.reset(new pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer(renderer, renderWindow,
        "viewer", false));
    view->setupInteractor(ui.openGLWidget->interactor(),
        ui.openGLWidget->renderWindow());
    ui.openGLWidget->setRenderWindow(view->getRenderWindow());

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud(
        new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
    cloud->width = 100;
    cloud->height = 10;
    cloud->points.resize(cloud->width * cloud->height);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < cloud->points.size(); ++i)
    {
        cloud->points[i].x = 1024.0f * rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
        cloud->points[i].y = 1024.0f * rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
        cloud->points[i].z = 1024.0f * rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
    }

    pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerGenericField<pcl::PointXYZ> fildColor(cloud, "z");
    view->addPointCloud(cloud, fildColor, "cloud");
    view->setPointCloudRenderingProperties(pcl::visualization::PCL_VISUALIZER_POINT_SIZE, 5, "cloud");
    view->spin();
    ui.openGLWidget->update();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QtPCLDemo w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"

When the program starts running, it looks like this:

After rotating the perspective, it became like this:

and like this:


I tried to display this point cloud using the C++ console and PCL library, and rotating the perspective can fully display the point cloud.
How do I use VTK to display point clouds in Qt, so that they can be fully displayed even when rotating the perspective?

It seems this problem is too uncommon. Perhaps try the Qt Forum? If you happen to find an answer, consider posting it here to benefit future readers. Good luck.
